# Weblogic server and Jersey servlet issue

Tags: jersey, weblogic

I start the Oracle Weblogic Server 12c R2 (12.2.1) on Eclipse, it can be synchronized, but has some issues below.  I have added the Jersey library 1.17, not sure if it is too old version. But I could find the correct download link for the latest.

```
        一月 24, 2016 11:20:39 上午 weblogic.wsee.runtime.JMSStoreRoutableIDMapper onFailure
        INFO: Destination Failure for weblogic.wsee.BufferedRequestQueue due to exception: While trying to lookup 'weblogic.wsee.BufferedRequestQueue' didn't find subcontext 'wsee'. Resolved 'weblogic'
        一月 24, 2016 11:20:39 上午 weblogic.wsee.runtime.JMSStoreRoutableIDMapper onFailure
        INFO: Destination Failure for weblogic.wsee.BufferedResponseQueue due to exception: While trying to lookup 'weblogic.wsee.BufferedResponseQueue' didn't find subcontext 'wsee'. Resolved 'weblogic'
        <Jan 24, 2016 11:21:15 AM EST> <Warning> <JAXRSIntegration> <BEA-2192509> <Changing servlet class from com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer (web.xml) to org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.> 
        <Jan 24, 2016 11:21:15 AM EST> <Warning> <JAXRSIntegration> <BEA-2192510> <Cannot add Jersey servlet for application class com.sun.jersey.api.core.ResourceConfig because ApplicationPath annotation is not set on it.> 
        <Jan 24, 2016 11:21:15 AM EST> <Warning> <JAXRSIntegration> <BEA-2192510> <Cannot add Jersey servlet for application class com.sun.jersey.api.core.ApplicationAdapter because ApplicationPath annotation is not set on it.> 
        <Jan 24, 2016 11:21:15 AM EST> <Warning> <JAXRSIntegration> <BEA-2192510> <Cannot add Jersey servlet for application class com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.DeferredResourceConfig because ApplicationPath annotation is not set on it.> 
        <Jan 24, 2016 11:21:15 AM EST> <Warning> <JAXRSIntegration> <BEA-2192510> <Cannot add Jersey servlet for application class com.sun.jersey.api.core.ClassNamesResourceConfig because ApplicationPath annotation is not set on it.> 
        <Jan 24, 2016 11:21:15 AM EST> <Warning> <JAXRSIntegration> <BEA-2192510> <Cannot add Jersey servlet for application class com.sun.jersey.api.core.DefaultResourceConfig because ApplicationPath annotation is not set on it.> 
        <Jan 24, 2016 11:21:15 AM EST> <Warning> <JAXRSIntegration> <BEA-2192510> <Cannot add Jersey servlet for application class com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig because ApplicationPath annotation is not set on it.> 
        <Jan 24, 2016 11:21:15 AM EST> <Warning> <JAXRSIntegration> <BEA-2192510> <Cannot add Jersey servlet for application class com.sun.jersey.api.core.servlet.WebAppResourceConfig because ApplicationPath annotation is not set on it.> 
        <Jan 24, 2016 11:21:15 AM EST> <Warning> <JAXRSIntegration> <BEA-2192510> <Cannot add Jersey servlet for application class com.sun.jersey.api.core.ClasspathResourceConfig because ApplicationPath annotation is not set on it.> 
        <Jan 24, 2016 11:21:15 AM EST> <Warning> <JAXRSIntegration> <BEA-2192510> <Cannot add Jersey servlet for application class com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig because ApplicationPath annotation is not set on it.> 
        <Jan 24, 2016 11:21:15 AM EST> <Warning> <JAXRSIntegration> <BEA-2192511> <The list of resource packages: org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs;com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application>
```

Could someone help to figure out how to fix this?

Web.xml is:

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
          <display-name>com.youtube.rest</display-name>
          <welcome-file-list>
            <welcome-file>readme.html</welcome-file>
            <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
            <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
            <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
            <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
            <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
            <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
          </welcome-file-list>

          <servlet>
            <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
            <init-param>
              <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
              <param-value>com.youtube.rest</param-value>
            </init-param>
            <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
          </servlet>
          <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
          </servlet-mapping>

        </web-app>

readme.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Read Me</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

If u need to mantain Jersey 1.X you must to declare this in weblogic.xml

```
   <wls:prefer-application-packages>
            <wls:package-name>com.sun.jersey</wls:package-name>
    </wls:prefer-application-packages>
```

Answer (score 0):

change the Jersey version to the 2.x

Answer (score 0):

These messages are issued when references to old Jersey 1.x components in the application web.xml are translated into Jersey 2.x references at the deploy time.  In other words, while Jersey 1.1 style web.xml definitions ARE supported, the implementation is upgraded to Jersey 2.x.

To get rid of these messages, the path is following:

- Upgrade your application to use Jersey 2.21.0 (JAX-RS 2.0 reference
  implementation provided by WLS 12c). You may have to deploy
  `ORACLE_HOME\wlserver\common\deployable-libraries\jax-rs-2.0.war`
  depending upon your WLS 12c version.
- Either package the RESTful Web
  Service Application Using web.xml With `javax.ws.rs.core.Application`
  Subclass
- Or package the RESTful Web Service Application Using web.xml
  Without `javax.ws.rs.core.Application` Subclass

See the following documentation link for detailed instructions: https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1221/wls/RESTF/deploy-restful-service.htm